# Enable action creator to not dispatch an action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an the following action creator:

```
export const toggleLoginModal = () => {
  return {
    type: "TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL",
  };
};
```

I'm using it on my container with connect():

```
export default connect(null, {toggleLoginModal})(MyComp);
```

This is a 'dumb' action creator - It always returns the same object.
I would like it to check if the user is already logged in by checking the redux store, and if the user is logged in, it should not dispatch any action at all.

I thought about returning a null in the action creator but I think this is bad practice... 
Also, returning an action which means "Ignore this action" also seems not right...

Is it possible for an action creator to not dispatch an action at all? 
If so, how will this be incorporated in the connect method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you have three options:

1. Prevent invoking `toggleLoginModal` by wrapping the `isLoggedIn` logic in your component
2. Work with `redux-thunk` to access the store and optionally not `dispatch` an action at all
3. Handle this sort of logic in your reducer, though I would probably think twice about it.

Examples:

Example 1: This assumes that you can tell whether or not the user is logged in by looking at the state

```
class MyComp extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {!this.props.isLoggedIn && <button onClick={() => toggleLoginModal()}>Toggle</button>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Example 2: Using `redux-thunk` middleware, assuming you have an `auth` reducer or something similar.

```
function toggleLoginModal () {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { auth } = getState();

    if (auth.isLoggedIn) {
      return;
    }

    dispatch({
      type: "TOGGLE_LOGIN_MODAL",
    });
  };
}
```

I would go for hiding the button altogether if this fits your requirements (example 1).